# Setting Background color to transparent in Plotly plots

Tags: python, plotly, transparency, plotly-python

My python code creates a plotly bar plot, but the background is white in color. I want to change it into transparent color. Is that doable?

***My Code:***

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *
py.sign_in('username', 'api_key')
data = Data([
Bar(
    x=['Sivaranjani S', 'Vijayalakshmi C', 'Rajeshwari S', 'Shanthi Priscilla', 'Pandiyaraj G', 'Kamatchi S', 'MohanaPriya', 'Madhumitha G', 'Franklin Alphones Raj J', 'Akfaris Almaas', 'Biswajit Champati', 'Priya R', 'Rekha Rajasekaran', 'Sarath Kumar B', 'Jegan L', 'Karthick A', 'Mahalakshmi S', 'Ragunathan V', 'Anu S', 'Ramkumar KS', 'Uthra R'],
    y=[1640, 1394, 1390, 1313, 2166, 1521, 1078, 1543, 780, 1202, 1505, 2028, 2032, 1769, 1238, 1491, 1477, 1329, 2038, 1339, 1458],
    text=['Scuti', 'Scuti', 'Cygni', 'Scorpii', 'Scuti', 'Pollux', 'Scorpii', 'Pollux', 'Scuti', 'Pollux', 'Scorpii', 'Scorpii', 'Scuti', 'Cygni', 'Scorpii', 'Scuti', 'Scuti', 'Pollux', 'Scuti', 'Pollux', 'Pollux'])])
plot_url = py.plot(data)
```

***The graph looks like this:***

[image]

Answer (score 170, accepted):

For a fully transparent plot, make sure to specify both the paper bgcolor and the plot's:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *
py.sign_in('', '')
data = Data([
    Bar(
        x=['Sivaranjani S', 'Vijayalakshmi C', 'Rajeshwari S', 'Shanthi Priscilla', 'Pandiyaraj G', 'Kamatchi S', 'MohanaPriya', 'Madhumitha G', 'Franklin Alphones Raj J', 'Akfaris Almaas', 'Biswajit Champati', 'Priya R', 'Rekha Rajasekaran', 'Sarath Kumar B', 'Jegan L', 'Karthick A', 'Mahalakshmi S', 'Ragunathan V', 'Anu S', 'Ramkumar KS', 'Uthra R'],
        y=[1640, 1394, 1390, 1313, 2166, 1521, 1078, 1543, 780, 1202, 1505, 2028, 2032, 1769, 1238, 1491, 1477, 1329, 2038, 1339, 1458],
        text=['Scuti', 'Scuti', 'Cygni', 'Scorpii', 'Scuti', 'Pollux', 'Scorpii', 'Pollux', 'Scuti', 'Pollux', 'Scorpii', 'Scorpii', 'Scuti', 'Cygni', 'Scorpii', 'Scuti', 'Scuti', 'Pollux', 'Scuti', 'Pollux', 'Pollux']
    )
])

layout = Layout(
    paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
)

fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

plot_url = py.plot(fig, filename='transparent-background')
```

Comment: Thanks! 
For those who want more options, here is the official documentation: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout

Comment: Nice, actually it is the opacity parameter(equal to 0) in rgba that makes the background transparent.

Comment: You could also: ```fig.update_layout(height=300, paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)", plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)")```

Comment: I'd recommend also adding `modebar = dict(bgcolor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)')` to make the modebar render nicely too.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the a Layout to change its colours with the parameters `bgcolour` and `opacity` set to yours desires. You could do something like:

```
data = Data([Bar(... The same you already have...)])

layout = Layout(
    title='Your Title',
    (xaxis, yaxis, WHAT EVER YOU WANT TO SET)

    paper_bgcolor='rgb(233,233,233)', # set the background colour

)
fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.plot(fig)
```

you can find some examples [here](https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to apply the transparent settings to an existing Plotly figure is to:

```py
fig.update_layout(
    {
        "paper_bgcolor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
        "plot_bgcolor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks doug this is exactly what I came looking for - super simple and straightforward makes it even better.