# How to set background color, title in Plotly (python)?

Tags: python, r, django, plotly

Below is my code, could someone tell me how do I set background color, title, x-axis y-axis labels :

```
scatterplot = plot([Scatter(x=x.index,
                            y=x['rating'],
                            mode='markers', 
                            marker=dict(size=10,
                                        color=x['value'],
                                        colorscale='Viridis', 
                                        showscale=True),
                            text=(x['value'] + ' ' + x['Episode'] + '<br>' + x['label']))],
                            output_type='div'
                  )
```

P.S : this is being shown in webpage directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can **set background color** by creating a Layout object

```
layout = Layout(
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
)

data = Data([
    Scatter( ... )  
])

fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot(fig, output_type='div')
```

If you want a transparent background see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968152/python-setting-background-color-to-transparent-in-plotly-plots).

**To set the title and axis labels**, add properties to the Layout object ([see the docs](https://plot.ly/python/figure-labels/)):

```
title='Plot Title',
xaxis=dict(
    title='x Axis',
    titlefont=dict(
        family='Courier New, monospace',
        size=18,
        color='#7f7f7f'
    )
),
yaxis=dict(
    title='y Axis',
    titlefont=dict(
        family='Courier New, monospace',
        size=18,
        color='#7f7f7f'
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem and helped me to know how this works.