# Plotly: How to change the background color of each subplot?

Tags: python, plotly, background-color

I am trying to create different subplot and I want for each subplot to have a different background color. I'm using plotly and it makes the thing a little bit more difficult. Any idea? I think the equivalent in matplot is face_color or something like this.

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=list(range(sample_points)),
        y=data_gx.iloc[scene],
        name='X-axis',
        line=dict(color='green', width=2)
    ),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=list(range(sample_points)),
        y=data_ax.iloc[scene],
        name='X-axis',
        line=dict(color='green', width=2)
    ),
    row=1, col=2
)
```

Comment: If you want to run the code in your local and check the output, change x and y with this of both graphs so just to see some output. 
"""
 x=list(range(10)),
 y=list(range(10)),
"""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[-1,2],y= [2,2],fill='tozeroy'),row=1, col=1)
```

This worked for me. This will draw a line from (-1,2) to (2,2) and will color everything below this points. It can help you color your background of each subplot just by adding in the row and col of subplots. It worked for me, I hope it will work for you too.

Comment: That works too. But now you have to make sure that the trace you're using to give a background color does not cover any *other* traces. With `shapes` you have the option to specify the placement as `layer='below'` to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor = "white")

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, it still does not seem that you can set [different background colors](https://community.plotly.com/t/subplots-different-background-color/7025) for the different subplots directly:

> The background color is set in layout for the figure:
>   plot_bgcolor='rgb(245,245,240)'. At the moment you cannot change the
>   backround of a particular subplot.

***BUT*** you are free to place shapes anywhere you'd like on both subplots by referencing both x axes through `xref=x` and `xref=x2` in `fig.update_layout(shapes=dict())`. And if you make sure to tweak a few other parameters as well like the zeroline and `layer='below'` you'll get a result thats pretty good:

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
# imports
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': {0: 1.0,
                              1: 2.0,
                              2: 3.0,
                              3: 4.0,
                              4: 5.0,
                              5: 6.0,
                              6: 7.0,
                              7: 8.0,
                              8: 9.0,
                              9: 10.0},
                             'A': {0: 15.0,
                              1: 6.0,
                              2: 5.0,
                              3: 4.0,
                              4: 3.0,
                              5: 2.0,
                              6: 1.0,
                              7: 0.5,
                              8: 0.3,
                              9: 0.1},
                             'B': {0: 1.0,
                              1: 4.0,
                              2: 2.0,
                              3: 5.0,
                              4: 4.0,
                              5: 6.0,
                              6: 7.0,
                              7: 2.0,
                              8: 8.0,
                              9: 1.0},
                             'C': {0: 12.0,
                              1: 6.0,
                              2: 5.0,
                              3: 4.0,
                              4: 3.0,
                              5: 2.0,
                              6: 1.0,
                              7: 0.5,
                              8: 0.2,
                              9: 0.1}})
# set up plotly figure
fig = make_subplots(1,2)

# add first bar trace at row = 1, col = 1
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['Index'], y=df['A'],
                     name='A',
                     marker_color = 'green',
                     opacity=0.4,
                     marker_line_color='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                     marker_line_width=2),
              row = 1, col = 1)

# add first scatter trace at row = 1, col = 1
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Index'], y=df['B'], line=dict(color='red'), name='B'),
              row = 1, col = 1)

# add first bar trace at row = 1, col = 2
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['Index'], y=df['C'],
                     name='C',
                     marker_color = 'green',
                     opacity=0.4,
                     marker_line_color='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                    marker_line_width=2),
              row = 1, col = 2)

fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)')

# Define gridlines and zerolines
# => an invisible zerolines looks better
# in this scenario
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False),
                  yaxis=dict(showgrid=True, zeroline=False),
                  xaxis2=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False),
                  yaxis2=dict(showgrid=True, zeroline=False),

)

fig.update_layout(
    shapes=[
        # 1st highlight during Feb 4 - Feb 6
 dict(
            type="rect",
            xref="x",
            yref="paper",
            x0=df['Index'].iloc[0]-1,
            y0=-0.001,
            x1=df.index[-1]+2,
            y1=1,
            fillcolor="steelblue",
            opacity=0.5,
            layer="below",
            line_width=0,
        ),
        # 2nd highlight during Feb 20 - Feb 23
        dict(
            type="rect",
            xref="x2",
            yref="paper",
            x0=df['Index'].iloc[0]-1,
            y0=-0.001,
            x1=df.index[-1]+2,
            y1=1,
            fillcolor="firebrick",
            opacity=0.5,
            layer="below",
            line_width=0,
        )
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: This is aprox what I want to do but instead of having the same color background, I want for each plot a different background. For the first lightblue, for the second red or something else. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I think you can easily change the background with the `paper_bgcolor`and `plot_bgcolor` layout options.

Here is a related question posted long ago: [Python -- Setting Background color to transparent in Plotly plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968152/python-setting-background-color-to-transparent-in-plotly-plots)