Changing some subplots' layout in plotly
Is there a way to change the layout not for the whole figure, but only a single (or several) subplot(s) in a figure (plotly 5.22)? Example code:
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


x = np.random.rand(2000)
y1 = np.random.rand(2000)
y2 = np.random.randn(2000)

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1, mode='markers'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2, mode='markers'), row=1, col=2)

# I want this to affect only the first subplot
fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='#ff0000')

fig.show()

I know there are methods to apply a function for each xxx like fig.for_each_trace() or fig.for_each_xaxis(), but there's no fig.for_each_subplot().
I have no idea how to address any subplot in the figure particularly except for functions that take the row and col parameters, like fig.add_trace().

It seems this question has already been asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61631230/plotly-how-to-change-the-background-color-of-each-subplot
